# Send json with unicode char throw WCF services

Tags: c#, json, wcf, unicode

I'd like create Rest json Api for some site. Site will work with russian text, so I should escape cyrilic symbols.

I create сontract IService1, implementation Service1 and class CompositeType

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(string type);
}

[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate ="{type}")]
    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(string type)
    {
        return new CompositeType { StringValue = "Hello Иван" };
    }
}
```

So, this service return {"StringValue":"Hello Иван"}. Russian symbols has not been escaped.

I can change CompositeType

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    private string _stringValue;

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char c in _stringValue)
            {
                if (c > 127)
                {
                    // This character is too big for ASCII
                    string encodedValue = @"\u" + ((int)c).ToString("x4");
                    sb.Append(encodedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        set { _stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

But service works wrong too. I recive double back slash.
{"StringValue":"Hello \\u0418\\u0432\\u0430\\u043d"}

How to do it right?

Comment: "Site will work with russian text, so I should escape cyrilic symbols." No, you shouldn't. JSON is UTF-8, and everything consuming JSON should understand that... why do you think you need to escape those characters? (Fundamentally, let the infrastructure do escaping for you. That's its job.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd like say that Jon Skeet absolutely right. Value of json can be any unicode char and cyrillic symbols too.

But if you should replace any no Ascii symbol to \uXXXX, you can use  Newtonsoft.Json;
Example implementation IService1

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "{type}")]
    public Stream GetDataUsingDataContract(string type)
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeNonAscii };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CompositeType { StringValue = "Hello Иван" }, settings);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    }
}
```